# Release build fails with microsoft .net native 1.7

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, .net-native

I have an error while building my uwp project for release, here is the output:

```
1>  Generating native code
1>  Generating fixups for native code
1>C:\Users\τασος\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : RHBIND : error RHB0016: Import of '' failed: bad file extension (must be .obj or .lib).
1>C:\Users\τασος\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Users\τασος\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\x64\ilc\Tools\rhbind.exe @"C:\Users\τασος\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AuebUnofficial\AuebUnofficial\obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\rhbindargs.ΟΠΑ-AUEB.rsp"' returned exit code 16
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

and the lines

```
<LoggerBasedExecTask 
      Condition="'$(UseDotNetNativeLogger)'=='true'"
      Application="$(_IlcExePath)" 
      Parameters="$(_IlcInvocationParameters)" 
      MessageLog="$(_IlcIntermediateRootPath)ilclog.csv"
      UseCommandProcessor="false" 
      >
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="_IlcExitCode" />
    </LoggerBasedExecTask>
```

I dont know where is the error but this is huge. Everytime i open vs2017 i discover a new bug...

Comment: I work on the .NET Native team. Can you shoot me a mail with an ilcRepro file? (dotnetnative@microsoft.com) https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/ilcRepro.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to downgrade the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` nugget package to `5.2.2`. After that, i was able to create .appxs for the store or build on Release.

Comment: 5.4.0 works as well
However this problem at all made me to recreate app "from scratch" to update it to latest platform packages

Comment: I think the problem exists in some releases of the library. Or maybe its just a problem with the caching in .nuget folder. Eitherway its painfull

Comment: Deleting the .vs folder and then opening the project in Visual Studio 2019 did it for me.